# Continue CSS animation on page load?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want my CSS animations for the elements in my header.php to continue smoothly on different pages.

So if I had a 200 second looped animation and 80 seconds in I clicked on the about us page the animation would still be 80 seconds in on page load?

Is this even possible and if so, how? Thanks.

Comment: if you can get the current animation's status on page exit and send it on to the next page, then that next page can simply start the animation at that point. but good luck reliably detecting when the page is exiting.

Comment: You'd probably be better off leaving the header in place and using AJAX to load the new page contents/adjust the URL.

Comment: You don't provide enough information to let us know how to help you. In order to do a modification in your page without touching the header animation, my advice is to use properly Javascript to change the part you want to modify, letting the other part of your page web untouched.

Comment: You would have to look into something like AngularJS or other modern javascript libraries that support virtual DOMs. The current way of structuring a website, especially with PHP, the page will be completely reloaded each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if it's some sort of keyframes animation like:

**CSS**

```
 @keyframes colorchange {
    0% {background: red;}
    50% {background: green;}
    100% {background: yellow;}
 }
 div {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: red;
     -webkit-animation: colorchange 5s linear infinite; 
     animation: colorchange 5s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: colorchange 5s linear infinite;
 }
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var animationTime=0;
     var intId = setInterval(function(){
         animationTime++;
     },1000);
     var postTime = function(link){
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: link,
         data: {'variable': animationTime},
        });
     }
     $('a').click(function(){
           window.onbeforeunload = postTime($(this).attr('href'));
     })
  })
```

**PHP**

```
   $myval = $_POST['variable'];
   echo "$('div').css('animation-delay', '-".$myval."s')"
```

You can use negative animation delay to start animation from some point, but in any way, this method is not perfect, but worth a try.

**P.S** But better use AJAX for page reload in such cases :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick rough thought

```
time = 200000;
var distance = 300;
window.currentTime = 0;

$('#element').animate({ left: distance },
{
  duration: time,
  step: function(now, fx) {

    window.currentTime = Math.round((now*time)/distance);

  }
});

$('a').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "http://yoururl.com/?startingPoint=" + (time - window.currentTime);        
});
```

then in each file do something like

```
if($_GET['startingPoint']){
    echo 'time = '.$_GET['startingPoint'];
}
else{
    echo 'time = 200000';
}
```

in place of the javascript time variable, i apologize if theres bugs in this, literally just pulled this out of my butt, but the concept is there, and no ajax needed.